# How to make ext4 update files in place during writes

Tags: filesystem, security, ext4

This question consists of two parts:

How to find out what is the writing
   mode of ext4?

How to configure an
   existing ext4 (a journaling file
   system) to do writes to a file in
   place such that shredding/wiping can
   be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext[234] always does update in place.  You don't have to do anything.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the question (or maybe it was me). Note: "such that shredding/wiping can be effective", the question is about how to make the file system overwrite, delete and update files instead of just changing the inodes and metadata.

Comment: Yes, and my answer is that is the normal way things work.  If you open a file and overwrite its contents, then it is overwritten in place.

Comment: Correct, that's the ext4 default: data=ordered (*) All data are forced directly out to the main file
system prior to its metadata being committed to the
journal.

Comment: However, I'm still not entirely sure what happens during multiple shredding passes: does the file system commit just the last version similar to the way dirty pages are saved?

Comment: shred forces the data out between passes.

Comment: At the moment `ext4` doesn't do update in place when `data=ordered` or `data=journal`. But only with `data=writeback`.

Comment: I don't think this answer is canonically correct. Please look at https://opensource.com/article/17/5/introduction-ext4-filesystem
and comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this accurately answers the question.  If a file is open for reading (say, by a shared library with its contents loaded in memory), you *really* don't want those contents over-written unexpectedly.  So, I believe the normal way (ie when data=ordered) is to write the data to disk, update the inodes/metadata, point the directory entry to the new file, but leave the old file in-place and allocated until all references to it are removed (that is, all processes have released any file_open handles).

In that case, shred/wipe might force an fsync, but the old file is still very much active which means it won't get shredded.

Comment: +1 that's right, just checked practically.

Comment: I agree. Journaling means copies of "overwritten" data may still exist on the filesystem after the write process is complete and all pointers and links are updated. May still exist until re-used, that is. The "shred" utility overwrites entire partitions, but I don't think that is the ask here.